# Prevent duplicate voting when there's more than one possible selection?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to set up a voting system in using Django that limits a registered user to voting only once on a single vote (despite there being multiple options available agree/strongly agree/disagree). So far, I've been able to set up a system where they can't make the same exact vote (so they can't vote "agree" twice), but they can change their vote and it still goes through (so they can vote "agree" and then vote again as "disagree"). I want them to be limited to one vote per topic, and I can't quite figure out how to tweak my code to accomplish this. Here is my view:

```
def vote(request, prediction_id):
    prediction = get_object_or_404(Prediction, pk=prediction_id)
    selected_choice = prediction.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])

    if Voter.objects.filter(prediction=prediction, choice=selected_choice, user_id=request.user.id).exists():

        return render(request, 'predictions/detail.html', {
            'prediction': prediction,
            'error_message': "Sorry, but you have already voted."
        })

    else:

        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        Voter.objects.create(prediction=prediction, choice=selected_choice, user_id=request.user.id)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('predictions:results', args=(prediction.id,)))
```

and here are my models:

```
class Prediction(models.Model):
    prediction_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    # ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.prediction_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    prediction = models.ForeignKey(Prediction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

class Voter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice)
    prediction = models.ForeignKey(Prediction)
```

Comment: You may want to redesign your models to have a `Topic` model, a 'Choice' model and a 'VoterChoice' model, where 'VoterChoice' has attributes `topic`, `user`, `choice` and a unique constraint on (`topic`, `user`).

Comment: How exactly would I put the unique constraint there? I believe that the topic/user/choice models you mentioned are equivalent to my prediction/choice/voter models, they just have different names. The only part I'm really struggling with, I think, is limiting the Voter  by placing that unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

```
if Voter.objects.filter(prediction=prediction, user_id=request.user.id).exists()
```

This line code say if this user have voted in any choice.

If i can understanted, the class Prediction is the "question". So other solution is:

```
class Voter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice)
    prediction = models.ForeignKey(Prediction)

Meta:
    unique_together = (("driver", "prediction"),)
```